# Table: how to merge two cells?

Tags: tables, combine

I can't figure out how to merge two rows as in figure below.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\date{10 dicembre 2015}

\maketitle

 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Text & \\
\hline 
Diametro fori (mm) & 4\\
\hline 
Passo x (mm) & 24\\
\hline
Passo y (mm) & 24\\
\hline
Altezza canale (mm) & 10\\
\hline
Lunghezza canale (mm) & 146\\
\hline
Numero fori & 39\\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
   \captionof{table}{Caratteristiche della piastra e del canale}
    \label{tab:dati_canale-piastra}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You actually merge cels from two adjacent columns (concluded from your picture)

Comment: If one of the answers fits your needs, consider to accept them please

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Text} \tabularnewline` in the relevant row. `\multicolumn{n}{q}{foo}` merges `n` cells with type `q` and places `foo` as content.

Side note: Using `booktabs` and vertical lines in a table is not the best design. I would also use left alignment for the first column.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \title{Title}
  \author{Me}
  %\date{10 dicembre 2015}

  \maketitle

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Text} \tabularnewline
      \hline 
      Diametro fori (mm) & 4 \tabularnewline
      \hline 
      Passo x (mm) & 24\tabularnewline
      \hline
      Passo y (mm) & 24\tabularnewline
      \hline
      Altezza canale (mm) & 10\tabularnewline
      \hline
      Lunghezza canale (mm) & 146\tabularnewline
      \hline
      Numero fori & 39\tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Caratteristiche della piastra e del canale}
    \label{tab:dati_canale-piastra}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since you're already loading the `booktabs` package, you should give serious thought to improving the overall "look" of the table by (a) getting rid of all vertical lines, (b) getting rid of most horizontal lines, and (c) using the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` of the `booktabs` package for the remaining three horizontal lines. With these changes in place, figuring out how to get rid of the unwanted central vertical divider in the header row becomes unnecessary. Note that, in the table below, I also suggest not using `c` (centering) for both columns; instead, I recommend `l` (left-alignment) for the first column and `r` (right-alignment) for the second column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, margin=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lr @{}}
\toprule
Text  \\
\midrule
Diametro fori (mm) & 4\\
Passo x (mm) & 24\\
Passo y (mm) & 24\\
Altezza canale (mm) & 10\\
Lunghezza canale (mm) & 146\\
Numero fori & 39\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Caratteristiche della piastra e del canale}
\label{tab:dati_canale-piastra}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use multicolumn command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{TITLE}} \\\hline
Value1 & Value2 \\\hline
Value1 & Value2 \\\hline
Value1 & Value2 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**: 
As correctly mentioned below, you don't need the multirow package to use the multicolumn command.

Comment: For `multicolumn` you not need `multirow package ...

Comment: The `c` specifier should be `|c|` most likely

Comment: Good points! You are right!

Comment: @MarcoMoschettini: Well, there's no `multicolumn` package ;-)

Comment: You may also want to explain in more detail your choice of using a `table` environment where the OP used a `center` environment, as well as the choice not to center the contents of the `table` environment.