# Latex table subdivided columns and rows

Tags: tables, texshop, booktabs

I'm new to Latex and am working TexShop on a MAC OS.

I wanted to create a table with subdivided columns and rows to describe my data, but I seem to have no luck trying to do it with the help of booktabs or array. Basically creating the column where i divide Group A into two more columns, and group B into two more columns is where I'm stuck.

Could somebody please help me out with how to create this kind of table?

[image]

EDIT: I want to make the titles bold and colour the table, like we can in Word or Powerpoint. Also, I want to get rid of the horizontal line on the two ends of the top row.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\newlength\Colwd
\setlength\Colwd{1.2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Affected} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Unaffected} & Total\\
\hline
& Kids & Adults & Kids & Adults&\\
\hline
Male & 144&15&34&89&282\\
Female & 37&6&66&109&218\\
Total&181&21&99&198&500\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There are plenty of existing questions about merging cells on the site: [How to merge cells vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72945/106162), [How to create a table with merged columns and rows, and wrapped text, like in MS Word?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112849/106162), [Table: how to merge two cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282923/106162) is there anything in particular holding you back?  Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with what you have so far?

Comment: You might search for `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`, but I would say that this table layout should definitely be optimized.

Comment: @DaiBowen Sorry, I've added the MWE.

Comment: @TeXnician Hello. Could you please give me suggestions on how i could optimise it better?

Comment: @Ar1229 I've tried my best (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

- use `booktabs` (toprule, midrule, cmidrule, bottomrule)
- do not center-align numbers (mostly they should be right-aligned)
- remove unnecessary boundaries (lines, horizontally and vertically)
- add some whitespace (it helps to be more readable)
- put a headline above *every* column

[image: table]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
Gender& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Affected} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Unaffected} & Total\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& Kids & Adults & Kids & Adults&\\
\midrule
Male & 144&15&34&89&282\\
Female & 37&6&66&109&218\\\addlinespace
Total&181&21&99&198&500\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much better than what I had, and more readable as well. But this table does not show up on my list of tables and I'm guessing it is because of the grouping option? How do I keep the table like this, but also get it to come up as a table in my list of tables?

Comment: @Ar1229 No, it does not show up, because you do not use the `table` environment around `tabular` and do not have a caption.

Comment: Okay thats why my `\caption{Demogrpahics}` didnt work. Any tips on how I can get it to come up?

Comment: @Ar1229 (1) Use the table environment around tabular and caption. or (2) use the `caption` package and add `\captionof{figure}{Demographics}`.

Answer (score 0):

After many years (almost five), meanwhile are available new table packages `tabularray` and `nicematrix`, your image of table is simple to reproduce. For example, by use of `tabularray`, you can write:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\NewTableCommand\scc{\SetCell{bg=cyan!15}} % set cell color

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines={1pt, orange}, vlines={1pt, orange},
                 colspec = {Q[c, wd=4em, font=\large\bfseries] 
                       *{5}{Q[c, wd=4em, si={table-format=3}]}},
                 row{1}  = {font=\large\bfseries},
                 rows    = {bg=cyan!30},
                 rowsep  = {1ex}
                 }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  {{{Affected}}}
                &       & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  {{{Unaffected}}}
                                    &           & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  {{{Total}}}   \\
        &{{{Kids}}} &{{{Adults}}}   &{{{Kids}}} & {{{Adults}}}  &       \\
Male    &\scc 144   &\scc 15        &\scc 34    &\scc  89       & 282   \\
Female  &\scc  37   &\scc  6        &\scc 66    &\scc 109       & 218   \\
Total   & 181       & 21            & 99        & 198           & 500   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]